# Spring MVC Rest App - Best Practice to Loading Properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Have been assigned to re-assess a Spring 4 MVC Rest app where previous developers
where placing the loading of the configuration properties inside the following places:

WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:mydatabase.xml" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.rest, com.myapp.config" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <util:properties id="props" location="classpath:prop.properties" />
</beans>
```

src/main/resources/mydatabase.xml:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholder"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="location" value="file:/opt/database.properties">
</property>

<bean id="mydatabase" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName"><value>${db.driver}</value></property>
    <property name="url"><value>${db.url}</value></property>
    <property name="username"><value>${db.username}</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>${db.password}</value></property>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="50" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="100" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="1" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="0"></property>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1000"></property>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1000"></property>
</bean>
```

src/main/resources/prop.properties:

```
banner = images/banner.png
```

Inside the code, I've been seeing people use the follow way to insert the banner file location:

```
private @Value("#{props[banner]}") String banner;
```

My objective is to add a new properties file:

```
src/main/resources/config.properties
```

So, I can use the @Value annotation...

Question(s):

1. What's the *BEST* way to reorganize some of these config files?
2. Where would I declare this new config.properties file and what is the declaration?

Comment: In Spring boot you can just add additional properties in the application.properties file. Then inject the value using @Value. Something like @Value("${com.test.config1}") private String config; You can scope your config like how you name packages to avoid config name collisions.

Comment: Sorry, this is not Spring Boot - its Spring 4 MVC...

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the property files in `src/main/resources`.

2.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {

   @Bean
   public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
      return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
   }
}
```

If you want to load multiple files, use [PropertySources](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySources.html)

`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is deprecated in favor of `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` for years now. I hope you'll ditch the XML and move to JavaConfig for, if not anything else, type safety.